# pandas how do i add an empty column after every nth column

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have this DataFrame

```
col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
   1a    2a    3a    4a    5a
   1b    2b    3b    4b    5b
   1c    2c    3c    4c    5c
   1d    2d    3d    4d    5d
```

I am trying to get this

```
col_1 col_2 NaN col_3 NaN col_4 NaN col_5 NaN
   1a    2a NaN    3a NaN   4a  NaN    5a NaN
   1b    2b NaN    3b NaN   4b  NaN    5b NaN
   1c    2c NaN    3c NaN   4c  NaN    5c NaN
   1d    2d NaN    3d NaN   4d  NaN    5d NaN
```

Basically from col_2 onwards, insert an empty column after every col_
How do i go about doing this?
i have tried

```
N = len(df.columns) #
for i in range(0,N): #
    df.insert(i,'','',allow_duplicates=True)
```

Comment: no the empty column start after the col_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[df.insert(i, '', np.nan, allow_duplicates=True) for i in range(df.shape[1], 1, -1)]
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2     col_3     col_4     col_5    
0    1a    2a NaN    3a NaN    4a NaN    5a NaN
1    1b    2b NaN    3b NaN    4b NaN    5b NaN
2    1c    2c NaN    3c NaN    4c NaN    5c NaN
3    1d    2d NaN    3d NaN    4d NaN    5d NaN
```

Comment: @BenedictNg - there's a better way to express your feeling, namely to click the check mark next to the answer to accept it.

Comment: @anky Yes,  `insert` is one of the few "inplace" operations in pandas.  Meaning that the operation takes place on the dataframe in memory and doesn't return an object.

Comment: Ahh , yes My bad sorry :) didnt check the final df output

Comment: No need to apologize.